# Draw under NSSlider

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

I have problem with drawing custom `NSSlider`. 
I have `NSView` with some subviews (including `NSSlider`). I setup order of subviews in `nib` file, but, when my view is presented on screen, all subviews drawn above `NSSlider`. This is wrong drawing ordering, subviews must be drawn under `NSSlider`. I don't known why this happens. `NSSlider` must be under all others views. Maybe, someone can explain me what is wrong?

Comment: This seems contradictory : *"my view [...] displays above NSSlider. This is wrong [...]"* followed by your *"NSSlider must be under all other views"* .  What exactly is the expected outcome?

Comment: I'm sorry. Question text updated.